# How to create data frames from rdd of word's list

Tags: pyspark

I have gone through all the answers of the stackoverflow and on internet but nothing works.so i have this rdd of list of words:

```
tweet_words=['tweet_text',
 'RT',
 '@ochocinco:',
 'I',
 'beat',
 'them',
 'all',
 'for',
 '10',
 'straight',
 'hours']


**What i have done till now:**

Df =sqlContext.createDataFrame(tweet_words,["tweet_text"])

and 

tweet_words.toDF(['tweet_words'])

**ERROR**:

TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the above code, you are trying to convert a list to a DataFrame.  A good StackOverflow link on this is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35009289/1100699.

Saying this, here's a working version of your code:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

# Create RDD
tweet_wordsList = ['tweet_text', 'RT', '@ochocinco:', 'I', 'beat', 'them', 'all', 'for', '10', 'straight', 'hours']
tweet_wordsRDD = sc.parallelize(tweet_wordsList)

# Load each word and create row object
wordRDD = tweet_wordsRDD.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
tweetsRDD = wordRDD.map(lambda t: Row(tweets=t[0]))

# Infer schema (using reflection)
tweetsDF = tweetsRDD.toDF()

# show data
tweetsDF.show()
```

HTH!

Comment: There is lots of data in the tweet_words list so can I use the variable tweet_words in sc.parallelize() method.

Comment: Yes, I've updated the above sample to access the variable `tweet_wordsList`.  HTH!

Comment: Hi Denny, TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable  is occuring

Comment: Is this happening just at the sc.parallelize(list)?  Or further down line?