# How to create a dataframe from a list using SparkSession?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to create a pyspark dataframe with one column of specified name containing a range of integers (this is to feed into the ALS model's recommendForUserSubset method).

So I've created a list of integers using range, and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001229/create-dataframe-from-list-of-tuples-using-pyspark) showing how to make a list into a dataframe using SQLContext. But since I'm using the SparkSession API, not the older one, I don't know how to create a SQLContext--and per the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html) on SQLContext I probably shouldn't have to: "As of Spark 2.0, this is replaced by SparkSession. However, we are keeping the class here for backward compatibility."

This is the code I'm trying to replace:

```
dataset = sqlContext.createDataFrame(range(i, i+1000), ['session_idx'])
```

I also don't know if I should be mapping the list of integers to a list of tuples or if it'll "just work".

Comment: Trying to create a column with a range of integers, I say that in the first sentence. The above did end up giving me a type error when I switched to calling createDataFrame on spark, which I thought would go away when I changed it to a list of tuples using:

[tuple(x) for x in range(i, i+1000)],

but the type error persisted. "TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <type 'int'>"

So i have no idea what was going on there. I switched to using SparkSession's range method instead.

Comment: see my answer below, it should clarify you what the error was suggesting

Answer (score 4):

In this case, the same method (spark.createDataFrame) exists on SparkSession.

However, for the specific use case of getting a range column, there's also a dedicated method for that:

```
dataset = spark.range(i, i + 1000)
dataset = dataset.withColumnRenamed('id', 'user_idx')
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think anyone would see this question before I finished answering it... My intention for posting the question was to fill a google gap rather than to actually get help, since "create a dataframe from a list using sparksession pyspark" wasn't returning anything immediately useful for me and it's such a basic question I don't think everyone should have to dig through the documentation for it when they're new to spark.

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
dataset = sqlContext.createDataFrame(range(i, i+10), ['session_idx'])
```

would **certainly give you errors**

> > TypeError: Can not infer schema for type:

The error is because `range(i, i+10)`  has to be the following as explained in api documentation

> > data: an RDD of any kind of SQL data representation(e.g. row, tuple, int, boolean, etc.), or :class:`list`, or :class:`pandas.DataFrame`

**Solution**

Just make `range(i, i+10)` **a list** as

```
i=0
dataset = sqlContext.createDataFrame([range(i, i+10)], ['session_idx'])
```

which would give you

```
+-----------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|session_idx|_2 |_3 |_4 |_5 |_6 |_7 |_8 |_9 |_10|
+-----------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|0          |1  |2  |3  |4  |5  |6  |7  |8  |9  |
+-----------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Or **a list of list** as

```
i=0
dataset = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[range(i, i+10),]], ['session_idx'])
```

which would generate

```
+------------------------------+
|session_idx                   |
+------------------------------+
|[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]|
+------------------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful